# Replicating this PUT request in RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Below is what the request looks like in the web app.

```
Request URL:http://myurl.com/rest
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 Ok
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:60
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:ui_dom_other=block; session=sessionkey; acct_table#pageNavPos=1; ui_usr_feat=block
Host:http://myurl
Origin:http://myurl.com
Referer:http://myurl.com/referer
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Request Payload view parsed
{"table":"users","settings":[{"name":"dnd","value":"true"}]}
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json
```

The data is in the request payload field

```
{"table":"users","settings":[{"name":"dnd","value":"true"}]}
```

Below is my current C# RestSharp code

```
            // Initiate Rest Client
            var client = new RestClient("http://myurl.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("resturl/restrequest");
            // Set headers, method and cookies
            request.Method = Method.PUT;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddCookie("session", sessionKey);
            // Set Data format
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            // Set Data
            string theString = "{'table':'users','settings':[{'name':'dnd','value':'true'}]}";
            request.AddBody(theString);
            // Execute
            var test123 = client.Execute(request);
```

I've been able to successfully do all my GET/POST calls however PUT has not been successful.

**Fiddler Capture**

Web App - Working

```
PUT http://myurl HTTP/1.1
Host: http://myurl
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 60
Origin: hhttp://myurl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://myurl
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ui_dom_other=block; session=sessionkey; acct_table#pageNavPos=1; ui_usr_feat=block

{"table":"users","settings":[{"name":"dnd","value":"true"}]}
```

C# Application - Not Working

```
PUT http://myurl HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.0.1.0
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: http://myurl
Cookie: session=sessionkey
Content-Length: 10
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<String />
```

Comment: how is it not successful? what are the differences between what you want and what you currently get?

Comment: It should be updating the backend value for dnd to true like the web app. At the moment it just doesn't update that value. And there's no response returned for either a successful or unsuccessful call. I'll get a wireshark capture and add it to the question in a moment.

Comment: fiddler capture will be better

Comment: I do note your JSON payload uses single quotes for strings `'table':'users'` instead of double quotes which is correct: `"table":"users"`

Comment: I've added the Fiddler capture of both the web app and c# app.

It seems that the data I'm adding via RestSharp isn't being added..

Comment: @wal I've tried using double quotes (escaped) but it does not work either.

Comment: Your exact code produces a different outcome for me using Restsharp 103.2 - see http://imgur.com/3w9tYes 
Interestingly your `Content-Type` is still text/xml - that is definitely wrong so perhaps you need to recompile? can you change something else to ensure that everything is recompiling? perhaps a Console.Out statement

Comment: Well that's disconcerting.

Comment: I'm able to send objects but the string doesn't seem to show up. How would you format the data into a C# object? Not sure how to add the array part after settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66695/discussion-between-wal-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a string as the payload consider adding an object:

```
request.AddBody(new { table = "users", settings = new[] { new { name = "dnd", value = "true" } } });
```

Comment: This was a success. The data is now showing correctly in the fiddler capture and has updated the backend accordingly.

Comment: I have to wait 23 hours to award bounty. I will be sure to follow through.